# discord.js "displayAvatarURL" low resolution

Tags: discord, bots, discord.js

I have a question about programming a Discord bot using discord.js. Well, when I use "displayAvatarURL" the user's avatar is shown to me, but in very low quality. Is there any way to improve this quality?

Answer (score 0):

You issue is quite simple to fix, according to [the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ImageURLOptions), you can pass an object as parameter to set the image's size, like this :

```js
user.displayAvatarURL({ size: 2048, dynamic: true });
```

I've also added the `dynamic: true` to let the GIFs avatars be animated ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can pass an object as a parameter to set the image's size :

```
user.displayAvatarURL({size: yourSize, dynamic: true});
```

In order to set a valid size, check [the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ImageURLOptions).

I added `dynamic: true` to animate the animated profile pictures.

Answer (score -1):

That's not a big issue you can add the following code for avatar code.

```js
.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true })
```

**Note**:- **Adding any format or size parameter may work glitchy for some avatars.**

Comment: Not true, this will only make the avatar animated, which would keep the resolution as is